# Why does Mininet have default IP Addresses of 10.x.x.x/8 for hosts?

Tags: ip, mininet, sdn

When I created my Mininet topology, by default the hosts were assigned IP addresses from the 10.x.x.x/8 network. Is there a specific reason behind it or was it just developed that way?

Answer (score 0):

10.0.0.0/8 is the class of private IP addresses that allows the maximum number of hosts. So, to let *Mininet* 's users simulate even large networks.